# Is the "naive" version of Chevalley's theorem still true?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, schemes

Reposting from math.se in case more people are interested here.

Chevalley's theorem says that if $f \colon X \to Y$ is a morphism of finite presentation of schemes and $C \subset X$ is constructible, then $f(C)$ is constructible. Here, constructible means $C$ is contained in the algebra of sets generated by retrocompact opens. I'm interested, for no particular reason, in whether this remains true under weaker assumptions:

- What if the morphism is merely finite type and not finite presentation?
- What if, instead of taking the usual definition of constructible, we just take finite unions of locally closed sets?

In other words, can one produce a counterexample to the following claim?

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a morphism of finite type and $C \subset X$ a finite union of locally closed sets. Then $f(C)$ is also a finite union of locally closed sets.

Comment: Just a quick comment that making the change in your first bullet point but not your second produces a false statement, if $f$ is the closed immersion associated to an ideal that's not finitely generated and $C=X$.

Comment: The m.se post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452666/counterexample-to-one-version-of-chevalleys-theorem

Comment: Let $Y$ be $\text{Spec}\ A$ for $A=k[y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n,\dots]$, and let $X$ be $\text{Spec}\ A[x]/I$ where $I$ equals $\langle (y_n-1)(y_nx-1)\rangle_{n\geq 1}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr probably I'm miscalculating, but won't the image of that set be (naively) constructible? Let A be the locally closed locus cut out by $(x_i - x_j)$ for all i, and $x_1 \neq 0$. Let $B$ be the closed locus cut out by $(x_i - x_j)(x_j - x_k)(x_i - x_k)$ for all triples $i,j,k$ of distinct indices. Let $C$ be the open locus which is the union, over all $i \neq j$, of the locus where $x_i \neq x_j, x_i \neq 0, x_j \neq 0$. Then I think your image set is $A \cup (B \cap C)$.

Comment: You are correct.  That was a bad example.

Comment: I emailed Johan de Jong about this question and he gave an example which you can find here: https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/commit/2d965db93cc960158c0fde4d585176afab2fbc9b.